# jQuery UI class switching of multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, class

Im trying to make the divs change class from "normal" to "thin" **ONLY** if they have the class "normal". But somehow they just change back and forth, the **IF** statement seems to be written completely wrong :)

Here is the code

```
<div class="normal">1</div>
<div class="normal">2</div>
<div class="normal">3</div>
<div class="normal">4</div>
<div class="normal">5</div>
<div class="normal">6</div>
```

CSS:

```
.normal{
float:left;
height:200px;
width:100px;
border:1px dotted gray;
}

.thin{
float:left;
width:50px;
height:200px;
border:1px dotted gray;
background-color:#5a5a5a;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document.body).click(function () {
  $("div").each(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("normal")) {
      $(this).toggleClass("thin", 300);         //Problem here?
    } else {
      this.style.color = "red";
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Why are you toggling the class? Do you need to revert that class when event get triggered again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Egis as per your requirement the code should like below :

```
$(document.body).toggle(
    function () {
        $("div.normal").animate({
            width: "50px",
        }, "slow", function(){ $(this).addClass("thin"); });
    },
    function(){
        $("div.normal").animate({
            width: "100px",
        }, "slow", function(){ $(this).removeClass("thin"); });
    }
);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eLyCA/)**

I hope this is what you are looking for, Good Luck !!

Answer (score 1):

ToggleClass (http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) will both add and remove the class.  So instead, you want to remove the class "normal" and add the class "thin":

```
$(this).removeClass("normal").addClass("thin");
```

Regarding the animation, it looks like you are using the jQueryUI project (sorry I missed the tag, the first time around): [http://jqueryui.com/toggleClass/](http://jqueryui.com/addClass/) which allows you to specify an animation duration.  With that in mind, you can include the durations:

```
$(this).removeClass("normal", 300).addClass("thin", 300);
```

Comment: It works but it doesn't have any animation. Just switches instantly. The goal is to make a good looking user interface so I need to animate it somehow now

Comment: If you need animations to make the UI 'good looking', you should probably redesign.

Comment: I agree that some a very nice design is possible without the use of animations and such, but I want to learn jQuery more so im trying to do all that kind of stuff..

Comment: Check out the Animate call: http://api.jquery.com/animate/.  If you get stuck, just post another question.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't remove the `'normal'` class after you have first reached the code block of your `if` and your `div` will always have the `'normal'` `class`, so your condition in your `if` will always be true.

Use `removeClass` for that purpose.

Also, if you want to change the `class` from `'normal'` to `'thin'`, use the `addClass` for adding `thin` instead of `toggle`.

EDIT:
Maybe this is what you want:

```
$(document.body).click(function () {
  $("div").each(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("normal")) {
      $(this).removeClass("normal");
      $(this).addClass("thin");
    }
    else if ($(this).hasClass("thin")) {
      $(this).removeClass("thin");
      $(this).addClass("normal");
    } else {
      this.style.color = "red";
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: The goal is for the divs to change with animation from "normal" to "thin" class. And change backwards is vise-versa.